# how to run instance in different through aws api tools

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

when i execute the command `ec2-describe-availability-zones` it shows

```
AVAILABILITYZONE    us-east-1a  available   us-east-1   
AVAILABILITYZONE    us-east-1c  available   us-east-1   
AVAILABILITYZONE    us-east-1d  available   us-east-1
```

so.. i can only run instance in us-east-1

how can i use other region if i want to run instance in other refion like ue-west-1?

i had copy ami form us-east-1 to us-west-1
and i execute  the command 
`ec2-run-instances ami-526a0662 -n 1 -k USweastOregon -g launch-wizard-2 --monitor`

it shows

`Client.InvalidAMIID.NotFound: The image id '[ami-526a0662]' does not exist`

Answer (score 1):

AMIs are region-specific. If you want to use an AMI in a different region, you must first [copy it](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2013/03/12/announcing-ami-copy-for-amazon-ec2/):

> To use AMI Copy, simply select the AMI to be copied from within the
>   AWS Management Console, choose the destination region, and start the
>   copy.  AMI Copy can also be accessed via the EC2 Command Line
>   Interface or EC2 API as described in the EC2 User’s Guide. Once the
>   copy is complete, the new AMI can be used to launch new EC2 instances
>   in the destination region.

The AMI in the new region will have a different AMI ID.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `--region` and specify `eu-west-1` or `us-west-1`.

```
 --region REGION
      Specify REGION as the web service region to use.
      This option will override the URL specified by the "-U URL" option
      and EC2_URL environment variable.
```